# "Begin" & "End" date based on values in a row

Tags: python, pandas

I have an example of input data that can be found [here](https://github.com/veronique-ka/tests/blob/master/input.xlsx)

**input**
[image]

I need to add 2 columns: "Begin_date" & "End_date" based on the data in each row:

- Begin date  - when all previous cells are empty and date starts from yyyymm01
- End_date - when **all** subsequent are empty:
- if all subsequent are not null, then something like "lifelong" date added: "99991231"
- otherwise - yyyymm30 or 31 or 28 (depends on month)

**Example of output:**

[image]

I will appreciate any ideas :) Thank you

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include the data as text rather than as an image (e.g. the text output from `df.head()` or similar)? It's unclear from what you've posted here what's actually in the "blank" cells - is it NA, is it an empty string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use pd.melt() 
sort data by id and date

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

df = pd.read_excel("input.xlsx")
max_date = df.columns[-1]

res = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id', 'region'], value_vars=df.columns[2:])
res.dropna(subset=['value'], inplace=True)

res.sort_values(by=['id', 'variable'], ascending=[True, True], inplace=True)

minimum_date = res.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep='first')
maximum_date = res.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep='last')

minimum_date.rename(columns={'variable': 'start_date'}, inplace=True)
maximum_date.rename(columns={'variable': 'end_date'}, inplace=True)

df = pd.merge(df, minimum_date[['id', 'start_date']], on=['id'], how='left')
df = pd.merge(df, maximum_date[['id', 'end_date']], on=['id'], how='left')

df['end_date'] = np.where(df['end_date']==max_date,
                          "99991231",df['end_date'])

df['start_date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'],format="%Y%m",errors='coerce') +MonthEnd(1)).astype(str)
df['end_date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'],format="%Y%m",errors='coerce') +MonthEnd(1)).astype(str)

df['end_date'] = np.where(df['end_date']=='NaT',
                          "99991231",df['end_date'])
print(df)
```

```
      id  region  201801  201802  ...  201905  201906  start_date    end_date
0  100001     628     NaN     NaN  ...    26.0    23.0  2018-09-30    99991231
1  100002    1149    27.0    24.0  ...    26.0    24.0  2018-01-31    99991231
2  100003    1290    26.0    26.0  ...    27.0    25.0  2018-01-31    99991231
3  100004     955    25.0    26.0  ...     NaN     NaN  2018-01-31  2018-12-31
4  100005    1397    15.0    25.0  ...     NaN     NaN  2018-01-31  2018-11-30
5  100006    1397    15.0    25.0  ...     NaN     NaN  2018-01-31  2019-02-28
```

Comment: Thank you very much @tawab_shakeel! This "MonthEnd" date-functionality is very helpful! I didn't know about it. Thanks!

Comment: @Vero No problem

Comment: @vero approve any answer which you find helpful so that more people can benefit from it

Answer (score 2):

Idea is convert non datetimelike columns to `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then convert columns to datetimes:

```
df = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx')

df = df.set_index(['id','region'])
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%Y%m')
```

Then create new columns by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), filter `January` columns, compare non missing values and get first value by [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html), then convert to output format by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for `begin`, for `end` first swap order with indexing `::-1` and get last non missing values, convert to last days of month and last get default value if last column is not missing value by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
begin = df.loc[:, df.columns.month == 1].notna().idxmax(axis=1).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
end1 = df.iloc[:, ::-1].notna().idxmax(axis=1) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()

end = end1.dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').where(df.iloc[:, -1].isna(), '99991231')

df.columns = df.columns.strftime('%Y%m')
df = df.assign(date_begin = begin, date_end =  end).reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df)
       id  region  201801  201802  201803  201804  201805  201806  201807  \
0  100001     628     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
1  100002    1149    27.0    24.0    27.0    25.0    24.0    26.0    27.0   
2  100003    1290    26.0    26.0    26.0    26.0    23.0    27.0    27.0   
3  100004     955    25.0    26.0    26.0    24.0    24.0    26.0    28.0   
4  100005    1397    15.0    25.0    26.0    24.0    21.0    27.0    27.0   
5  100006    1397    15.0    25.0    26.0    24.0    21.0    27.0    27.0   

   201808  ...  201811  201812  201901  201902  201903  201904  201905  \
0     NaN  ...      24    20.0    26.0    24.0    26.0    26.0    26.0   
1    28.0  ...      24    21.0    26.0    25.0    27.0    24.0    26.0   
2     NaN  ...      28     NaN    28.0    26.0    27.0    27.0    27.0   
3    27.0  ...      24    12.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
4    26.0  ...      25     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
5    26.0  ...      25    23.0    25.0    17.0     NaN     NaN     NaN   

   201906  date_begin  date_end  
0    23.0    20190101  99991231  
1    24.0    20180101  99991231  
2    25.0    20180101  99991231  
3     NaN    20180101  20181231  
4     NaN    20180101  20181130  
5     NaN    20180101  20190228  

[6 rows x 22 columns]
```

Also is possible create valid datatimes in both new column by [`Timestamp.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.max.html) with [`Timestamp.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx')

df = df.set_index(['id','region'])
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%Y%m')

begin = df.loc[:, df.columns.month == 1].notna().idxmax(axis=1)
end1 = df.iloc[:, ::-1].notna().idxmax(axis=1) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()

end = end1.where(df.iloc[:, -1].isna(), pd.Timestamp.max.floor('d'))

df.columns = df.columns.strftime('%Y%m')
df = df.assign(date_begin = begin, date_end = end).reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df)
       id  region  201801  201802  201803  201804  201805  201806  201807  \
0  100001     628     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
1  100002    1149    27.0    24.0    27.0    25.0    24.0    26.0    27.0   
2  100003    1290    26.0    26.0    26.0    26.0    23.0    27.0    27.0   
3  100004     955    25.0    26.0    26.0    24.0    24.0    26.0    28.0   
4  100005    1397    15.0    25.0    26.0    24.0    21.0    27.0    27.0   
5  100006    1397    15.0    25.0    26.0    24.0    21.0    27.0    27.0   

   201808  ...  201811  201812  201901  201902  201903  201904  201905  \
0     NaN  ...      24    20.0    26.0    24.0    26.0    26.0    26.0   
1    28.0  ...      24    21.0    26.0    25.0    27.0    24.0    26.0   
2     NaN  ...      28     NaN    28.0    26.0    27.0    27.0    27.0   
3    27.0  ...      24    12.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
4    26.0  ...      25     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
5    26.0  ...      25    23.0    25.0    17.0     NaN     NaN     NaN   

   201906  date_begin   date_end  
0    23.0  2019-01-01 2262-04-11  
1    24.0  2018-01-01 2262-04-11  
2    25.0  2018-01-01 2262-04-11  
3     NaN  2018-01-01 2018-12-31  
4     NaN  2018-01-01 2018-11-30  
5     NaN  2018-01-01 2019-02-28  

[6 rows x 22 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael! I always learn something new with your codes!